# Can not restart dnsmasq due to " configuration syntax check   [fail]"

Tags: dns, dhcp, dnsmasq, hostapd

I restart dnsmasq and get

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/dnsmasq restart
 * Restarting DNS forwarder and DHCP server configuration syntax check   [fail]
```

From where and how can I troubleshooting?

Answer (score 2):

dnsmasq can be configured by editing the file

```
 /etc/dnsmasq.conf
```

dhcp config file:

```
/etc/dhcp3/dhclient.conf
```

Comment: I have never modified these two configure files. Could you give me a example to configure dnsmasq, this issue hasn't been resolved yet.

Comment: check the following link: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Dnsmasq

Answer (score 0):

I found this link to be very helpful. It provides tips on how to check the syntax of the configuration file with `dnsmasq --test` as well as setting up logs you can read: https://superuser.com/q/681601/476811

I also suggest you read the manual to check that the syntax is being used correctly: http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/docs/dnsmasq-man.html There are different versions of dnsmasq, so make sure the syntax documentation matches the version you are using.